# Second dropdown list not binding at all

Tags: knockout.js

I have two observables:

```
self.areasAndProfessionsList = ko.observableArray();
self.selectedAreaFromDropList = ko.observable();
```

I get Json data and save it to `areasAndProfessionsList`. The structure of data is next:

```
{"Areas":[{"ID":1,"Name":"name", "Professions":[{"ID":1,"Name":"name1"}{"ID":2,"Name":"name2"}...
```

So, I have array in other array. Next, I make two dropdown lists. My binding for them looks like this:

```html
<select data-bind="options: $root.areasAndProfessionsList, optionsText: function(item) {return item.Name}, value: $root.selectedAreaFromDropList"></select>
<select data-bind="options: $root.selectedAreaFromDropList.Professions, optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
```

First binding works ok. It shows me the names of Areas. However, I can't get the second dropdown list to work properly. I've checked that `selectedAreaFromDropList` is not empty, and the console shows no errors. How can I get to the Name property to bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding to the *observable* `selectedAreaFromDropList`, instead of the actual item that is inside the observable. Execute the observable as a function to get the desired effect:

```html
<select data-bind="options: $root.selectedAreaFromDropList().Professions, 
                   optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9u7M3/) for a demo.